# Force.com CLI error

Tags: force-cli

I am testing Force.com CLI. I can autenticate but any else. I get this error in OSX- El capitan

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer
>   dereference

http://screencast.com/t/K87zZbHUFfj

Any idea?

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with `Apex` or `Lightning` as far as I can tell. Somewhat humorous that the error message commands you to panic though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you received is not exclusive to the [Force.com CLI](https://force-cli.heroku.com/), but it is due to the program attempting to access an invalid memory address or dereferencing a nil pointer and [Go](https://golang.org/) (the language the program is written in) throwing a runtime error.

According to the screenshot in your post, you receive the following error message after attempting to run the `force log` command:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>
> [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x2b9d9]

According to the [Go Documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/), the signal `0xb` represents a `SIGSEGV` (segmentation violation).

Some common causes of this type of runtime error include:

- Dereferencing a nil pointer
- Attempting to access an array element that is out of bounds
- Attempting to access memory for which the program does not have ownership
- Attempting to access too much memory
- Attempting to use an uninitialized pointer

One user had a [similar problem](https://github.com/ForceCLI/force/issues/291) when attempting to use the Force.com CLI on OS X El Capitan and was able to resolve the issue by changing the permissions on `~/.force/current/account` to be readable by the current user, rather than just the root user.